# Browse all servers at the same time

Tags: windows, web-browser, software-testing, dns

For a server that has loadbalancing via DNS, the host name will be resolved into several IP addresses. Typically, the browser will just choose one (the first?) and then display the web page.

For testing purposes, I should browse the website of all IP addresses and check whether the pages look the same.

Basically I could implement this myself, but I wonder if someone else had that issue already and found a solution that is stable and tested.

It must

- support HTTP 1.1 (of course)
- support up to 4 IP addresses
- cost less than 30 EUR
- run on Windows (7 x64)

Ideally it would show only one page and indicate if there are differences in other pages or not. If there are, compare the page side by side.

Comment: you want something that will do this automatically?  You could just edit your hosts file to avoid the IP resolution, and use winmerge or some other diff tool to compare the pages you get from each different IP.

Comment: @Adrien: yes, it should reduce the amount of work needed. Of course I could 1.) open `cmd` 2.) enter `nslookup` 3.) run `notepad` 4.) open `hosts` 5.) Alt+Tab to cmd 6.) mark the 1st IP 7.) Copy 8.) Alt+Tab to notepad 9.) Paste 10.) Alt+Tab to cmd 11.) mark the second IP 12.) Copy 13.) Alt+Tab to notepad 14.) Paste 15.) Alt+Tab to cmd 16.) mark the third IP 17.) Copy 18.) Alt+Tab to notepad 19.) Paste 20.) Alt+Tab to cmd 21.) Mark the fourth IP 22.) Alt+Tab to notepad 23.) Paste 24.) Press Ctrl+S 25.) Close notepad 26.) Close cmd 27.) Open a browser ... too few characters left